How to cycle colors on different plots
I have a series of five stacked plots using groupplot, with each plot featuring a single curve. I would like to color each curve differently, but I've noticed that the cycle list schemes only apply to plots within the same axis.
Specifically, my goal is to cycle through the 'Dark2-5' qualitative scheme palette from ColorBrewer, although this choice is not mandatory.
My current code is this one (as you see, I've tried several things without success):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,colorbrewer}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Definicions de paràmetres
    \def\fm{1} % freqüència de la moduladora
    \def\fc{10} % freqüència de la portadora
    \def\kfm{7} % índex de modulació per FM
    \def\kpm{2*pi} % índex de modulació per PM (derivada)
  \def\tfinal{2*2*pi*1/\fm}

  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style = {group size = 1 by 5, vertical sep = 5pt,},
    clip = false,
        axis lines=middle,
        height=3cm, width=7cm,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
        xmin=0, xmax=0.5+\tfinal,
        ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
        domain=0:\tfinal,
        samples=1000,
        ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick,}, % Aplica el gruix de 2pt a totes les línies
    cycle list/Dark2-5, % Aquí seleccionem l'esquema de colors Set1 de ColorBrewer
    cycle list name = Dark2-5,
    /pgfplots/cycle multiindex list={Dark2-5\nextlist},
    colormap/Dark2-5,
  ]
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot {sin(deg(\fc*\x))};
      \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Portadora, $p(t)$};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot {sin(deg(\fm*\x))};
      \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Moduladora, $m(t)$};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot {(sin(deg(\fm*\x)))*sin(deg(\fc*\x))};
      \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Modulació AM};
    \nextgroupplot
      % f -> f(t) = k·x(t). Aleshores la fase s'obté integrant això.
      \addplot {sin(deg(\fc*\x + \kfm*(1-cos(deg(\fm*\x)))))};
      \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Modulació FM};
    \nextgroupplot
      % phi(t) = k·x(t)
      \addplot {sin(deg(\fc*\x + \kpm*sin(deg(\fm*\x))))};
      \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Modulació PM};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Which produces:


You could try \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=i} before each \addplot with an increasing number i.

Something like this? I have added \addplot[<<color>>] for each function.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Definitions of parameters
    \def\fm{1} % modulating frequency
    \def\fc{10} % carrier frequency
    \def\kfm{7} % frequency modulation index
    \def\kpm{2*pi} % phase modulation index (derivative)
    \def\tfinal{2*2*pi*1/\fm}

    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=1 by 5, vertical sep=5pt,},
        clip=false,
        axis lines=middle,
        height=3cm, width=7cm,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
        xmin=0, xmax=0.5+\tfinal,
        ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
        domain=0:\tfinal,
        samples=1000,
        ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,
        every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
    ]
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[blue] {sin(deg(\fc*\x))};
            \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Carrier, $p(t)$};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[red] {sin(deg(\fm*\x))};
            \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize Modulator, $m(t)$};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[green] {(sin(deg(\fm*\x)))*sin(deg(\fc*\x))};
            \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize AM Modulation};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[orange] {sin(deg(\fc*\x + \kfm*(1-cos(deg(\fm*\x)))))};
            \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize FM Modulation};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[purple] {sin(deg(\fc*\x + \kpm*sin(deg(\fm*\x))))};
            \node[anchor=east] at (axis description cs:0,0.5) {\scriptsize PM Modulation};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



That was my first try. This works, obviously, but I was wondering if it's possible to assign automatically a different color to each plot, to avoid hard-coding them in each plot in case you add more plots. Just curious.
